# VBA button that converts decimal to octal/hexa

Tags: vba, button

I'm completely new to VBA and I'm trying to make a button convert a decimal number to octal and hexa. This is the code I've written for decimal to binary, but I have a hard time trying to make it do decimal to octa/to hexa.

```
Private Sub Conversion_Click()

ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear     'Supprime toutes les valeurs qui étaient auparavant sur la feuille
If (IsNumeric(ConversionInt.NbText)) Then    'Vérifie que le texte est bien un nombre entier et non une chaine de caractères
    If (Int(ConversionInt.NbText) / ConversionInt.NbText = 1) Then
        ConversionInt.Hide                                          'Cache le formulaire conversion
        Call Division(ConversionInt.NbText)                         'Effectue la division sur le nombre demandé
    Else: MsgBox "Vous devez rentrer un nombre entier"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Vous devez rentrer un nombre entier"  'Message d'erreur si on a pas un nombre entier

End If

End Sub
```

Would ove it if someone can help, thanks.

Comment: Do you wanna use this in MS-Excel? There you had already finished functions like "DEC2OCT". See [this link](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Convert-numbers-to-different-number-systems-880eeb52-6e90-4a9d-9e56-acaba6a27560#bmconverts_a_decimal_number_to_binary) for more informations.

Comment: @JoelGeiser Thank you for that, but I'm trying to make a button that when pressed, a window appears asking the user for a number. After entering the number, the program then shows another window showing the converted number.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? Excel has 2 built-in functions, `DEC2BIN` and `DEC2OCT`, both of which can be used from VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(123456)
End Sub
```

prints `1E240` in the immediate window

Excel also has a function `DEC2BIN` which for some reason doesn't accept input larger than 511. You can use a 2-step approach -- first using `DEC2HEX` and then convert each hex digit to binary:

```
Function Convert(num As Variant, num_base As Long) As Variant
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Select Case num_base
            Case 16:
                Convert = .Dec2Hex(num)
            Case 8:
                Convert = .Dec2Oct(num)
            Case 2:
                s = .Dec2Hex(num)
                Convert = .Hex2Bin(Mid(s, 1, 1))
                For i = 2 To Len(s)
                    Convert = Convert & .Hex2Bin(Mid(s, i, 1), 4)
                Next i
            Case Else:
                Convert = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        End Select
    End With
End Function
```

Tested like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = InputBox("Enter a number")
    MsgBox s & " is" & vbCrLf & _
        Convert(s, 2) & " in binary" & vbCrLf & _
        Convert(s, 8) & " in octal" & vbCrLf & _
        Convert(s, 16) & " in hex" & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

A typical run gives output like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the wheel if you want to reinvent it.
This function converts from Decimals to another numeric system.
This function will do the same as the Excel functions.

```
Function cn(ByVal n As Double, ByVal s As Double)
  'n the number to convert
  's the numberic system to convert to.
  'This function can convert to binary all the way to the length of the
  'digits string and all in between.

  Dim x As Double  'The exponent without decimals
  Dim xx As Double 'The exponent with decimals, if any
  Dim r As String  'The return string
  Dim p As Integer 'Posistion of the digit in the return string
  Dim L As Long    'Length of the string return string
  Dim d            '(d+1) because mid() does not accept 0.
                   'The position of the digit in the digits string.
 Dim v As Double   'The numeric value of the position 
                   'of the digit in the return string
  Dim digits As String
  digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Start:

  If n > 0 Then
     xx = Log(n) / Log(s)
     x = Int(xx)
  End If
  p = x + 1
  If r = "" Then
    r = String(p, "0")
    L = p
  End If
  v = s ^ x
  d = n \ v
  Mid(r, L - x, 1) = Mid(digits, d + 1, 1)
  n = n - (v * d)
  If n <> 0 Then GoTo Start
  cn = r
End Function
```